# Android authenticating with Kerberos

Tags: android, kerberos, xml-rpc

I am trying to create a Android application that uses an existing web service. However, the existing web service uses Kerberos for authentication and I am having trouble getting Android using the android-xmlrpc library to authenticate with the service. If anyone has any experience with this, please respond.

I am completely new to this kind of stuff, so any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: It would be helpful, if you described, what _exactly_ your problem is. What have you tried? Can you give some Code examples? Have you managed using xmlrpc whithout authentication in the first place? ...

Answer (score 2):

The [information](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/authentication.html) here helped me to get my android app working with kerberos. Here's a [link](https://github.com/klnusbaum/UDJ/blob/acoustics/androidApp/src/org/klnusbaum/udj/network/ServerConnection.java#L154) to a project I'm working on. It does kerberos authentication. Here's the pertinent code:

```
UsernamePasswordCredentials creds =
  new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password);
DefaultHttpClient client = getHttpClient();
client.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(SERVER_AUTH_SCOPE, creds);

boolean authWorked = false;
try{
  HttpGet get = new HttpGet(AUTH_URI);
  HttpResponse resp = client.execute(get);
  authWorked = hasValidCookie();
}
/*catch(AuthenticationException e){
Log.e("TAG", "Auth exceptions");
//TODO maybe do something?
}*/
catch(IOException e){
  Log.e("TAG", "IOException exceptions");
  //TODO maybe do something?
}
```

Here's the `getHttpClient()` method:

```
  public static DefaultHttpClient getHttpClient(){
    if(httpClient == null){
      httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
      final HttpParams params = httpClient.getParams();
      HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, REGISTRATION_TIMEOUT);
      HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, REGISTRATION_TIMEOUT);
      ConnManagerParams.setTimeout(params, REGISTRATION_TIMEOUT);
    }
    return httpClient;
  }
```

Here's `hasValidCookie()`

```
private static final String LOGIN_COOKIE_NAME = "CGISESSID";
private static boolean hasValidCookie(){
  for(Cookie cookie: getHttpClient().getCookieStore().getCookies()){
    if(cookie.getName().equals(LOGIN_COOKIE_NAME))
    {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Very interesting.  But the link to your github example is dead.  I'm trying to implement kerberos on android as well; it seems quite daunting.

Answer (score 1):

There is Hypergate ([hypergate.com](https://hypergate.com)) which is a Kerberos client for Android allowing other apps to request tickets. It's using the standard Android API, which means that WebView's and most Browsers work without any code changes. There is an SDK that allows you to integrate easily, which will manage the tickets for you.

Disclaimer: I'm an engineer at Hypergate